# MFC application (32-bit) behaving strangly on windows (7 64-bit) machine (garabage value from GetScrollPosition() function results)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

We have one MFC application which is working fine on windows server 2008 R2 (64-bit) and window 7 (32-bit). But it is behaving strangely on window 7 (64-bit) machine.

After debugging the applicaiton I found that the function call to `GetScrollPosition()` was giving the return values of `CPoint(x,y)` as garbage - the starting row and column number for the application are set as indefinite values and it is not able to call `Draw3DCellStep()` to draw cells.

One interesting thing happening here with my application is if I change the zoom level of the application to `<=70%` it is returning the currect `Cpoint(x=0,y=0)` Values, But if I modify the zoom value to 80% then `GetScrollPosition()` returns `Cpoint(x=0,y=58494736)`.

Why does the `GetScrollPosition()` function return garbage or inappropriate values? The same application is working fine on win 2003 R2 (64-bit) and win 7 (32-bit). Please help.

Note: It is developed in visual studio 2008 professional edition compiled on windows server 2003.

Comment: when i changed the windows7 theme to classic then this MFC application working correctly. But the window which should be created as dockable is displayed as normal window.

Answer (score 0):

After applying the windows Classic theme the MFC application working fine. So in the Windows7 Aero theme the legacy MFC application won't work properly.